# How to set admin attribute to true in rails console (pry)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now when I change User.first.admin = false, to User.first.admin = true it does not save.  Even if I run User.first.save afterwards.  While if I make

```
variable = User.first
variable.admin = true
variable.admin
```

it will return true(default is false)

But the user in my actual application is still not given the extra features they would be if admin = true, so how do I properly set admin to true for my first User in the rails console(with pry) ?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: where is User model to see it?

Comment: User model has admin attribute with boolean value, default value is set to false, its there and it works, should I still post the model's code?

Comment: variable.save instead of User.first.save

Comment: `user in my actual application` how do you detect the user that you want to give him admin proveledges to?

Comment: User.first as there is currently only one user

Comment: variable.save did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
User.first.update :admin => true
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, after variable.admin = true, you can just run

```
variable.save
```